Schengen Transit visa when travelling from India to Sweden
I am travelling to Sweden on a visitor visa from India.

visa type C
visa duration is 3rd August 2024 - 1st September 2024
stay duration is 15 days

We are planning to book flights from:

5th August (will reach Sweden around 11 AM)

to:

20th August (will reach India by 11:30 PM)

I have the following questions:

As the total duration of stay is coming down to 16 days, is it fine or should I book my flights on the 19th only?
The layover for this flight is in Munich, Germany. So would I need a transit visa for Germany, even if i don't want to leave the airport?


Of course if the max duration is 15 days and you stay 16 days this is not fine. You need to make sure your stay stays within the given limits.
Note that what counts is when you enter and exit the Schengen Area, not Sweden.
Also note that incidents such as delays and cancellations can happen, so it’s usually wise not to get right to the limit and make sure you have a little buffer.
Germany and Sweden are both in the Schengen Area. Your visa for Sweden is valid for your transit in Germany, you don’t need an additional visa. You will be going through passport control there, not in Sweden (the Germany-Sweden flight is a domestic Schengen flight).

Thanks for replying. @jcaron
so let's say i book my return flight from 5th - 19th August (on 19th, flight will leave Sweden by 6 AM and Munich by 12:30 PM) will that be fine? arrival time in India is 11:30 PM.
So this buffer is alright in your opinion? or should i book one day earlier i.e. 18th?
Also for Germany Munich, can I do site visits in Munich also or for that I would need a transit visa?

@Aadit I suppose it would take extremely bad luck not to be able to leave Germany in time if your original flight is at 12:30, but everyone has their own notion of risk. Once you have passed border control in Germany you can go anywhere in the Schengen Area, as long as you keep Sweden your main destination (I.e. the country where you stay the longest). But I’m not sure you have enough time to get to the city, do anything useful, and be back to the airport in time given your schedule.
